# Can someone help me fix this toString method please

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a method which converts string to a MeterNumber. The code is as follows.

```
public static MeterNumber fromString(String number) {
      MeterNumber mn = new MeterNumber(false);
      int i = 0, // position in number
          n = 0, // number of digits
          len = number.length();
      boolean valid = true;
      while (valid && i < len) {
         char c = number.charAt(i);
         i = i + 1;
         if (n < 9 && Character.isDigit(c)) {
            mn.digits[n] = c - '0';
            n = n + 1;
         } else if (Character.isWhitespace(c)) { 
            // skip spaces
         } else {
            valid = false;
         }
      }
      int cs = mn.checksum();
      if (valid && i == len && n == 9 &&
          cs / 10 == mn.digits[7] && cs % 10 == mn.digits[8]) {
         return mn;
      } else { 
         return null;
      }
   }
```

It's suppose to read an input like this:

```
531 481 889 O 788.5
652 364 795 P 2442.7
```

It will work fine if I just provide:

```
531 481 889
652 364 795
```

However it returns null if my input is in this format:

```
531 481 889 O 788.5
652 364 795 P 2442.7
```

Can you please help me see the problem. Why is the Char and double at the end of the line interfering?

This is the code calling for the method.

```
 private MeterNumber meterNumber; 


public static Meter load(Scanner sc) {
      MeterNumber meterNumber = MeterNumber.fromString(sc.nextLine());
      int n = 1;
      sc.nextLine();
      Tariff[] tariffs = new Tariff[n];
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         String kind = sc.next();
         sc.nextLine();
         if (kind.equals("P")) {
            tariffs[i] = PeakTariff.PEAK_TARIFF;
         } else if (kind.equals("O")) {
            tariffs[i] = OffPeakTariff.OFF_PEAK_TARIFF;
         } 
      }
      return new Meter(meterNumber, tariffs);
   }

public MeterNumber getMeterNumber() {
      return meterNumber;
   }

}
```

This is the code calling from my main method:

```
Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(new java.io.File("Readings.txt"));
        Meter meter = Meter.load(sc2);

        System.out.println(meter.getMeterNumber());
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `MeterNumber`?

Comment: It's a nine digit number

Comment: You need to provide Runnable code. So you need to show us code for `MeterNumber`

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but is there some requirement that prevents you from using Double.parseDouble() and Integer.parseInt()?

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera I edited my question to include the code involved

Comment: @MarsAtomic Am not exactly following what you are saying

Answer (score 0):

It returns null because you said it wasn't valid.

```
  while (valid && i < len) {
     char c = number.charAt(i);
     i = i + 1;
     if (n < 9 && Character.isDigit(c)) {
        mn.digits[n] = c - '0';
        n = n + 1;
     } else if (Character.isWhitespace(c)) { 
        // skip spaces
     } else { //this else is the problem
        valid = false;
     }
  }
```

You told it to set `valid` to false if it is neither whitespace nor a digit.  Since O and P are not digits or whitespace, it sets valid to false.

```
  if (valid && i == len && n == 9 &&
      cs / 10 == mn.digits[7] && cs % 10 == mn.digits[8]) {
     return mn;
  } else { 
     return null;
  }
```

The first thing the if statement checks is if it is valid.  Since it is not, it return null.